# Variable is not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, variables, vector

Here is my piece of code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "W.h"
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QPushButton>
#include <QtGui/QFont>
#include <QtGui/QWidget>
#include <QtGui/QLabel>
#include <QtGui/QImage>
#include <QtGui/QPainter>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QImage>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


void PainterWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
        vector <const char*> p;
        p.push_back("01.jpg");
        p.push_back("02.jpg");
        p.push_back("03.jpg");
        p.push_back("04.jpg");
        p.push_back("05.jpg");
        counter=counter%5;
        QImage img= QImage(p[counter]);
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.drawImage(0,0,img);
        counter++
        p.clear();

}
```

I get error "error: 'vector' was not declared in this scope"
I can't understand, I've already included vector library, why the error still appears?

Thanks everyone for help!

Comment: Try `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add:

```
using namespace std;
```

Or prefix `vector` with `std::`

By the way, you can optimize your code by creating and filling the vector once only. There is no point in doing this for every paint event. Also, no need to expicitly clear your vector when done, its destructor (called automatically in your case) does it.

```
static std::vector<std::string>& images()
{
    static std::vector<std::string> imagesVect;
    if ( imagesVect.empty() )
    {
        imagesVect.push_back("01.jpg");
        imagesVect.push_back("02.jpg");
        imagesVect.push_back("03.jpg");
        imagesVect.push_back("04.jpg");
        imagesVect.push_back("05.jpg");
    }
    return imagesVect;
}

void PainterWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
        counter=counter%5;
        QImage img= QImage(images().[counter].c_str());
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.drawImage(0,0,img);
        counter++;    
}
```

Comment: It's not the standard library that clears the vector. It's its own destructor that releases the memory it has allocated.

Comment: You are right, I meant the STL code....

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
std::vector<const char *>
```

that is use the qualified name of class vector declared in namespace std..